# Shuffling 2-Day array for memory match game

Tags: java, arrays, match, shuffle

Hello I'm trying to create a memory match game. I'm able to randomize the array states to get different values, but after I load 2x of 8 elements of the states array into an array called tempGrid[][], I can't seem to suffle the contents. For example, I get the result of:

```
AL AK AZ AR 
AL AK AZ AR 
CA CO CT DE
CA CO CT DE
```

but I'm trying to get

```
AK AL CA CT
CT DE CA AK
DE AL AR AR
CO AZ AZ CO
```

How can I accomplish this? thanks for any help. code below

```
import java.util.*;
public class createGrid
{

    private static String[][] tempGrid ={{"00", "01", "02", "03"},
                                      {"10", "11", "12", "13"},
                                      {"20", "21", "22", "23"},
                                      {"30", "31", "32", "33"},
                                     };

    static String[] states = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE",
                              "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", 
                              "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS",
                              "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", 
                              "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
                              "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV",
                              "WI", "WY"};
     static String[][] themeGrid = new String[4][4];
    public static void setThemeGrid()
    {   
        //filles temp grid with 8 elements x2
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++)
        {
            themeGrid[0][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[0][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[0][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[0][counter] = states[counter];

            themeGrid[1][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[1][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[1][counter] = states[counter];
            themeGrid[1][counter] = states[counter];

            themeGrid[2][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[2][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[2][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[2][counter] = states[counter+4];

            themeGrid[3][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[3][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[3][counter] = states[counter+4];
            themeGrid[3][counter] = states[counter+4];
        }
         //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(themeGrid);
         //doessn't seem to work

        System.out.println("This is the randomized theme grid");
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
            { 
                System.out.printf("%s ", themeGrid[row][column]);


            }System.out.println();
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        setThemeGrid();

    }     
}
```

Comment: When using `Arrays.asList(themeGrid)` you create a copy of your array as a list. This copy is then shuffled. So your array does not change. You need to hold a reference to the list and copy the result to your array.

Comment: Try shuffling each themeGrid[0][x] too, that might work. Problem is that with your general approach, each 'line' would keep its members. Write your own shuffle method instead. Or copy all the data into one array, shuffle that, then copy back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you're setting each element of themeGrid four times. But I believe this would do what you intended.

```
public static void setThemeGrid()
{   
    //fills temp grid with 8 elements x2
    List themeList = new ArrayList()
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        themeList.add(states[counter]);
        themeList.add(states[counter]);
        themeList.add(states[counter+4]);
        themeList.add(states[counter+4]);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(themeList);

    System.out.println("This is the randomized theme grid");
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            themeGrid[row][column] = themeList.get(row*4 + column);
            System.out.printf("%s ", themeGrid[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And if you wanted to be able to reshuffle the same grid easily, just save the themeList as a static variable instead of or in addition to the themeGrid.

Comment: actually, just glancing at this again, it would be easier to read if you put items into the list as:  "for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++) { themeList.add(states[counter]); themeList.add(states[counter]) } . Wanted to put this as a comment since the answer has been accepted. But I can't format the comment which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to randomize a list or array is to create a Comparator that returns a random value like this:

```
public class RandomComparator<T> implements Comparator<T>{
    private Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    public int compare(T a, T b) {
        return rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
    }   
}
```

You can use that RandomComparator with `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()` to randomize the order of any array or collection.

In the case of a multi-vector array like yours, you'll need to separately shuffle each 'row' and then shuffle the 'columns'. Maybe multiple times to get them good and mixed.